# "Exception: ... [nsIWebProgressListener::onStatusChange]" when using jQuery AJAX inside click event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hello I am new to ajax and I am using it along with jquery to load an html document inside an html div which is in another html document,the way I am achieving this is like this:

```
  function pageload()//page load is called on body onload event
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Marker.aspx',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
               $(".mainBar").html(data);
               alert("loaded");
            }
        });
}
```

this seems to work fine,the problems hits when I try to do this using some js events like this

```
$(".panelHead").click(function(){


     alert("clicked!");
       $.ajax({
        url: 'Marker.aspx',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
           $(".mainBar").html(data);
           alert("loaded");
        }
    });
```

I even tried creating onclick functions on button but the problem persist,It doesn't show any error in browser console,but simply doesn't load the document,I tried to debug using firebug it gives some jquery.js error which I don't understand the error is:

```
Timestamp: 06/01/2012 AM 11:43:25
Error: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "onStatusChange"' when calling method: [nsIWebProgressListener::onStatusChange]"  nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)"  location: "<unknown>"  data: no]
```

Comment: Does it happen to be an old version of jQuery by any chance?

Comment: have you placed your `click` event inside `<script>$('document').ready(function(){ //Your click handler });</script>`

Comment: Does it work once but does it ‘stop’ working when you click on a link that you just got back from the server (from the working Ajax call)?

Comment: What happens if `alert` is removed? (It can effect the "event dispatcher" in FF, although that doesn't seem related.) Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net case that shows this exception (for you)?

Comment: I downloaded jquery like couple of months ago,anyways would download again and try

Comment: @Snedden27 After quite a bit of googling, the only even-slight hint I can find towards it is that it's a low level method inside of Firefox that's in the process of being deprecated.  My guess is that old versions of jQuery still invoke it somehow.  (Very wild guess, but worth a try.)

Comment: I removed the alert ,and dowloaded this version of jqery http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js  but still I am trying yo figure out the problem

Comment: I have created  the js fiddle as u ask me to ,how to I share it here?,(js fiddle is new to me)

Comment: @Matijs it works only on body onload function and nothing else not on click function ,not on jquery .classname(clickevent) not even on $document.load event

Comment: @Snedden27 After you've typed your code in, hit the Save button near the top left of the page then copy/paste the URL.

Comment: @Corbin here http://jsfiddle.net/8BSNm/#update,most of the page is distorted as some files(background) and database is not connected and I don't know how to include them in jsfiddle,but I think this should be enough to elaborate the issue

Comment: @Snedden27 Can you whittle it down to a smaller example?  I'm not seeing the error; I'm just getting a bunch of missing resources and undefined properties errors.  Can you make the smallest recreation of it possible and post it?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not caused by jQuery, not jquery.js error. It is most like to be caused by some firefox extensions. Please try another browser like chrome.